# Oracle Query - Select row having end_date (may be NULL/EMPTY) greater than sysdate

Tags: sql, oracle

I have Oracle table `Demo_t`, having column `end_date` which may have value null. I want to select all rows having `end_date` greater than current date.

I have written query below

```
select * from Demo_t where NVL(End_date,sysdate+3) > sysdate;
```

No doubt, query is giving expected result but I want make sure that i am not missing something or that any other better solution exists. It will help me to better understand Oracle database more.

Thanks,

Comment: Why if end_date is null you put sysdate+3 instead?

Comment: Avoid using functions on data to achieve filtering; that is "non-sargable" (unable to use indexes). Way better to use a "sargable" alternative  e.g. **where ( end_date > sysdate or end_date IS NULL )** see answer by @kikyalex nb: because it involves an OR operator you may need to include parentheses if there are other conditions to consider

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `End_Date` is null then you take it in your results. Is that what you want?
If so you could write it like

```
SELECT *
FROM DEMO_T
WHERE END_DATE > SYSDATE OR END_DATE IS NULL;
```

If you don't want that, could try

```
SELECT *
FROM DEMO_T
WHERE END_DATE > SYSDATE;
```

<strike>In your code:</strike>

`NVL(End_date,sysdate+3)` actually increment `sysdate` for each row in your table, which isn't a good idea if you can simply check `End_Date` for null

Edit: As @Thorsten Kettner said, there is only one sysdate in query so it won't be calculated for each row

Comment: There is just one SYSDATE per query, hence only one SYSDATE+3. This value doesn't get computed per row. So your first query does the same as the original query and the execution plan is very likely to be the same. The difference is in which query one considers more readable.

Answer (score 1):

You query is fine. You can use that or check for NULL explicitely with `(end_date > sysdate or end_date is null)`. Both do the same and while some people prefer the former, others prefer the latter and still others always use `DECODE` to check nullable columns. Use what you consider most readable and stick to one way in all your queries (or in a team: use what your colleagues use). Stay consistent.

There is one way, though, you could speed up such queries: use a high fix date instead of `SYSDATE+3`, usually something like `DATE'9999-12-31'`. Then create a function index on this expression.

```
create index idx_end_date on demo_t ( nvl(end_date, date'9999-12-31') );
```

The matching query:

```
select * from demo_t where nvl(end_date, date'9999-12-31') > sysdate;
```

As the index covers *all* dates, it is much more likely to be used than a mere index on `end_date`. This can speed up queries immensely.

By the way: Be aware that `SYSDATE` contains a time part. If `end_date` only contains a date, then you may want to `TRUNC(SYSDATE)` in the comparision.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `trunc` for dates else it will compare time and might give wrong output.

```
select *   
  from Demo_t   
 where trunc(nvl(end_date,sysdate+1)) > trunc(sysdate);
```